# Add auto play feature to jquery localScroll slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow, scrollto, autoplay

I made a jquery image slider using the tutorial from [Line 25](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-sliding-feature-slideshow-with-jquery)

I'm trying to also add an autoplay functionality to it, but I can't seem to figure out any way at all to do it.  I tried adding a setInterval function to run the same .click function from this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
$("#slideshow-nav").css("visibility", "visible");
$("#slideshow-nav a[href=#slide1]").addClass("active");

$("#slideshow-nav").localScroll({
    target:'#slideshow', axis: 'x'
});

$("#slideshow-nav a").click(function(){
    $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

but I wasn't sure how to simply add 1 to the li id's (#slide1) through (#slide4).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.slide = 1
function nextSlide(){
   parseInt($(".active").attr("href").replace(/#slide/g,"")) == 4 ? window.slide = 1 : window.slide = parseInt($(".active").attr("href").replace(/#slide/g,"")) + 1;
   $('#slideshow-nav a[href=#slide'+window.slide+']').click();
}
setInterval(nextSlide,8000);
```

the above is assuming 4 slides.  if you have more or less, change the number 4.  Changes slide each 8 seconds (8000)